# Background position seems to be inaccurate

Tags: html, css

I've an image and I have put a mask over it.

The mask is divided into 3 equal parts. Each part has the same image as its background.
Each part has 1/3rd portion of image. I am changing background position of each part, so the masks (collectively) look exactly like the image.

Everything works great, but 2nd part has some issue in background-image, and it looks few pixels shifted to the right.

I need to remove that shifting.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8au8nhe5/2/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="main">
        <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/grasshopperpraying_mantis_195444.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div id="mask">
        <div class="part part1"></div>
        <div class="part part2"></div>
        <div class="part part3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<button id="switcher" class="main">Put mask on top</button>
```

**CSS:**

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 390px;
    height: 300px;
}
#main {
    z-index: 2;
}
#mask {
    z-index: 1;
}
#main, #mask, .part {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.part {
    background-image: url('http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/grasshopperpraying_mantis_195444.jpg');
    background-size: 390px 300px;
    width: 130px;
}
.part2 {
    background-position: -130px 0;
    left: 130px;
}
.part3 {
    background-position: -260px 0;
    left: 260px;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$('#switcher').click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('main')) {
        $(this).html('Put mask on top').removeClass('main');
        $('#main').css({
            zIndex: 1
        });
        $('#mask').css({
            zIndex: 2
        });
    } else {
        $(this).html('Put main on top').addClass('main')
        $('#main').css({
            zIndex: 2
        });
        $('#mask').css({
            zIndex: 1
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: css class .part1 is missing.is it a typo error? this may not solve the issue, but just asking. I don't find any issue in the fiddle..may be I need to clean my eyes :-)

Comment: Image size doesn't match its dimension thus resized and distorted. Is it ok to crop part of the image?

Comment: The mask should look exactly like the image. If cropping implies not showing some part of image, that is not allowed.

Comment: @Jashwant i don't know what for your waiting still, answer seems to be working

Comment: @sanojlawrence, yes solution works, but it asks to change `#wrapper` width, which is fixed in my case.

Comment: @Jashwant you need to change `#wrapper` width that's all what size you need

Comment: I cannot change the `#wrapper` width. Check my comment on Dharmang's answer. I hope that will help.

Comment: you have to post further clarifications what happen if you change width  **your question is unclear**

Comment: The image has an aspect ratio of 1.3364 while the mask is 1.3. Something has got to give. Either: (a) crop the image... it will be just 1-2 pixels (b) resize the image to match 1.3 (c) resize the mask to match 1.3364 (d) ignore the aspect ratio (which you are currently doing).

Comment: @SalmanA, I was hoping to find a way to change aspect ratio of background images of masked divs, so that they can be equal to aspect ratio of the real image.

Comment: @SalmanA, I've answered the question by using`img` tag. But still, any answer with the use of `background-image` would be awesome.

Comment: @Jashwant I now see the issue, that **there is no issue**. You are scaling both img tag and background image to same dimensions. This is correct and it should produce desired results. However, Chrome has peculiar rounding off errors. This error becomes prominent when you mix pixel measurements (in your case the background images is offset by one 1 pixel). This is a Chrome only issue; your fiddle works in FireFox in IE.

Comment: @SalmanA, I thought about that too, hence, I kept `width` of `#wrapper` as `390px`, as it is divisible by 3. What should be causing the issue now and how can I solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by Dharmang, cause of the issue was aspect ratio of image. And, it was not possible to fix, without changing the `#wrapper` dimension, or the image itself.

I've found a workaround, but using `img` tag, instead of `background-image`, so that I can distort the aspect ratio of images of `mask div`, in equal amount, as it is destroyed by the 'real image'.

```js
$('#switcher').click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('main')) {
        $(this).html('Put mask on top').removeClass('main');
        $('#main').css({
            zIndex: 1
        });
        $('#mask').css({
            zIndex: 2
        });
    } else {
        $(this).html('Put main on top').addClass('main')
        $('#main').css({
            zIndex: 2
        });
        $('#mask').css({
            zIndex: 1
        });
    }
});
```

```css
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 390px;
    height: 300px;
}
#main {
    z-index: 2;
}
#mask {
    z-index: 1;
}
#main, #mask, .part {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.part {
    width: 130px;
}

.part img {
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 390px;
    height: 300px;
}

.part2 {
    left: 130px;
}

.part2 img {
    margin-left: -130px; 
}

.part3 {
    left: 260px;
}

.part3 img {
    margin-left: -260px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="main">
        <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/grasshopperpraying_mantis_195444.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div id="mask">
        <div class="part part1"><img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/grasshopperpraying_mantis_195444.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="part part2"><img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/grasshopperpraying_mantis_195444.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="part part3"><img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/grasshopperpraying_mantis_195444.jpg" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<button id="switcher" class="main">Put mask on top</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

It is because you are using image of dimension 425x318 and resizing background to 390x300, so image gets distorted as aspect ratios of them do not match.

Check updated demo, here I have used wrapper dimension of same size as of image, i.e. 425x318.

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8au8nhe5/5/)

Update in code:

CSS

Remove background-size from .part and change #wrapper width, height.

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 425px;
    height: 318px;
}
#main {
    z-index: 2;
}
#mask {
    z-index: 1;
}
#main, #mask, .part {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.part {
    background-image: url('http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/grasshopperpraying_mantis_195444.jpg');
    /*background-size: 390px 300px;*/
    width: 130px;
}
.part1 {
    background-position: 0 0;
    left: 0;
}
.part2 {
    background-position: -130px 0;
    left: 130px;
}
.part3 {
    background-position: -260px 0;
    left: 260px;
}
```

UPDATE:

As you mentioned in comment that Image is not in control, `background-size` properties `contain` and `cover` also not working.

The only feasible option seems to get the image dimensions by some method (javascript OR server side code) and dynamically set the #wrapper dimensions to match image dimensions.

JavaScript Code: (For getting image dimensions and set Wrapper dimensions accordingly)

http://jsfiddle.net/8au8nhe5/19/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myImage = new Image();
    myImage.src = "http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/grasshopperpraying_mantis_195444.jpg";
    $(myImage).on('load', function() {
        console.log('My width is: ', this.naturalWidth);
        console.log('My height is: ', this.naturalHeight);
        $("#wrapper").css({"width": this.naturalWidth + "px", "height": this.naturalHeight + "px"});
    });
});
```

For Reference:
http://davidwalsh.name/get-image-dimensions
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement

Comment: Ha, beat me to it. Here's another jsfiddle, just has a source image having the original 390px width: http://jsfiddle.net/8au8nhe5/18/

Comment: wow....great eyes. It was distortion of image, rather than shifting of pixels. Just great. I was working on something more complex and this minute issue took almost a day. Thanks a ton.

Wrapper width is fixed. I cannot change. Any solution, by changing the `background-size` or anything else ?

Comment: Use image dimension same as wrapper :)

Comment: You can also try background-size: contain.

Comment: I don't control image, so cannot have the image with same dimension. `contain` does not work.

Comment: `#wrapper` width is fixed. I cannot change it. Actually, I've showed just a small part of my complex js slider. There are other images, with other dimensions. `#wrapper` is the `width` of the slider. It cannot be changed. But, it can contain images of different dimensions. Do let me know if you need further clarifications.

Comment: To avoid Image distortion, we must apply same aspect ratio (of image) to the wrapper div so it is required to change wrapper dimension. I don't see any solution other than this.

Comment: I think, you are right. I don't see a solution with this approach. May be instead of using background images, I should use `<img>` tag, that way I would be able to control aspect ratio, I guess.

Comment: I've answered the question by using`img` tag. But still, any answer with the use of `background-image` would be awesome.